# Innacurate query with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-like

Language is PHP, Database ORM is RedBean

```
if(isset($get['last']) || isset($get['first'])){        
    $query = '';
    $search_params = [];
    if(isset($get['first']) && !isset($get['last'])){
        //search only with first name
        $query .= ' AND name LIKE :first ';
        $search_params[':first'] = '%'.$get['first'].'%';
        $args['first'] = $get['first'];
    }
    else if(!isset($get['first']) && isset($get['last'])){
        //search only with last name
        $query .= ' AND name LIKE :last ';
        $search_params[':last'] = '%'.$get['last'].'%';
        $args['last'] = $get['last'];
    }
    else{
        //search with both first and last name
        $query = ' AND (name LIKE :first OR name LIKE :last) ';
        $search_params[':first'] = '%'.$get['first'].'%';
        $search_params[':last']  = '%'.$get['last'].'%';
        $args['first'] = $get['first'];
        $args['last'] = $get['last'];
    }   
    if($args['admin']){
        //if the user is the admin of the account they can see all transactions
        $args['transaction'] = admin_example($id, $query, $search_params);
    }else{
        //if the user is a member of the account and was involved in the transaction 
        $args['transaction'] = member_example($id,$user->email,$query,$search_params);
    }
}else{
    $args['transaction'] = false;
}

//get archived transaction the user was involved in matching search parameters
function admin_example($account_id,$query_segment,$search_params)
{
    $params = array_merge([':id'=>$account_id],$search_params);
    return R::getAll('SELECT name,tx_id,otp,property_type,property,ins_documents,active FROM transaction WHERE account_id=:id AND active="0" '.$query_segment.' ORDER BY name ASC',
        $params
    );
}

//get archived transaction the user was involved in for the current account and matching search parameters
function member_example($account_id,$email,$query_segment,$search_params)
{
    //gets transactions the account member is able to view.
    $params = array_merge([':account'=>$account_id,':email'=>$email],$search_params);
    return R::getAll('SELECT name,tx_id,otp,property,property_type,ins_documents,active FROM 
    transaction WHERE account_id=:account AND (primary_email=:email OR secondary_email=:email) AND active="0" '.$query_segment.' ORDER BY name ASC',
        $params
    );
}
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT 
    name,tx_id,otp,property_type,property,ins_documents,active 
FROM 
    transaction 
WHERE 
    account_id='1' AND active='0' AND (name LIKE '%ABC%' OR name LIKE '%DEF%') 
ORDER BY 
    name ASC
```

**Assume The Following:**

1. I type "ABC" into the first name input and "DEF" into the last name input.
2. The table has 1 row where the `active="0"` condition is met.
3. The name column of said row contains a Last Name and First Name, separated by a comma, ie `Flip, Tre`.

It seems that no matter what is typed into the input boxes, the record is always retrieved, when it should not be matching either of the LIKE statement.s I'm not sure why, and I'm wondering if there is anything else I can do? I already added an index to the `name` column but no dice. I also tried to use REGEXP however I was unable to retrieve anything like that.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @karthik MariaDB 5.5 in Development. WebScale in Production

Comment: The things with inverted commas don't need them. The things without inverted commas do!

Comment: @Uueerdo It's a typo.there are several variations of the query (which is a prepared statement), so i just condensed it for brevity.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the code involved in preparing the statement then.

Comment: @Uueerdo I would have to clear it with management. probably a pain in the ass. :-/

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm working on it.

Comment: since there's an `or` in there, i'd be willing to be your parenthesis aren't where you think they are.

Comment: @pala_ as you can see there are multiple versions of the query, so that isn't the problem. it fails for all cases. **EDIT**: i see a potential problem after a dump of the query but that only covers one case. its still innacurate with just one name: http://puu.sh/hLVgt/e77b52fc3f.png

Comment: and if you run your query directly against the db rather than through the ORM? are you able to post the row that is being returned? if the lastname is blank, your `or` becomes `or '%%'`, so that'll match everything...

Comment: @pala_ good idea , let me check.

Comment: Are the entries in `$get` unset, or empty? You may want to use `empty` instead of `isset`. Check `var_dump($get)` to be sure.

Comment: @JohnKugelman is on the right track - if either firstname or lastname is set to '' rather than not set at all, your `or` clause becomes `('%%' or '%%')`, which will match everything

Comment: @JohnKugelman You're correct, and i never even considered it. time to write some middleware to get rid of this problem. Also changing `OR` to `AND` for more granularity makes it acceptably accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, and your comment showing the issue, it looks like when `last` and `first` are empty on the form, they are still being passed through to the script.

This means that the `isset()` check is passed, but they have no value (ie, empty string, ie, `''`).  When this is added to your `or` clause, it will add `'%%'`, which will, obviously, match any value.

You will also need to check and make sure these variables are not set to empty strings before including them in your query. You can do that either by calling `isempty()` on the variable, or checking it for inequality against the empty string, `''`.

Comment: unfortunately, this now makes my question not salvageable. time for another 6 month question ban

Comment: how so? the root cause seems to have been established?

Comment: the rules state that a question must be helpful to future users with similar problems. This is too localized since its just a mental mistake on my part

Comment: I would disagree with your assessment - i have a sneaky suspicion this occurs more than anyone would like to admit to :D

Comment: god i feel so dumb haha

Comment: Eh, you're being hard on yourself for no reason. That's what this site is here for, to help you figure out a perplexing problem. Probably every PHP developer gets bit by the empty vs. isset distinction at some point.

Comment: @r3wt if this has answered your question - could you accept it? there's a good chance it'll be helpful to others

Comment: @pala_ Yep, i was waiting on **JohnKugelman** to write an answer since his comment ultimately solved my problem. no worries!

Comment: @r3wt ah. i felt enough ownership of the answer (i did comment immediately prior to his comment that it was the blank value causing your problem) to be okay with posting this. if i hadn't hit upon it as well, i wouldn't have anwered.